# sharepoint 2013 workflow is not showing stages and actions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

[SharePoint 2013 workflow logic not visible][1]

[SharePoint example][2]

I was trying to make workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 and when I choose list workflow, give name and select SharePoint 2013 workflow and appears windows no Stage no such thing. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4wsK.png

I followed this site [2]: https://www.sharepointsky.com/server-side-activities-have-been-updated-you-need-to-restart-sharepoint-designer-to-use-the-updated-version-of-activities/....and tried everything. It won't work in my system. I could not identify the issue.

Comment: You need to include more information in your questions if you want to get help. Configuration settings and error logs are good places to start. As this question exists now it has little chance of being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Awful issue. I don't know the reason but copying file:

```
"Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.Proxy.dll"
```

from any of your SharePoint sites where Workflow 2013 is available into this folder:

```
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\(Site where Workflow 2013 is missing)\15.0.0.4455"
```

will do the trick.

Let me know if it worked for you.